# null object reference в ListView в различных положениях экрана

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой. Есть метод, который меняет цвет у определенного элемента `ListView`. В портретном режиме все работает, но при переходе в ландшафтный режим выдает `null object reference` при вызове метода `lstView.getChildAt(num).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);`. До момента вызова этого метода все идет одинаково в обоих положениях экрана. По методу `lstView.getItemAtPosition(num).toString()` выдает одинаковую информацию, но именно на том методе все ломается. Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: может быть стоит показать код?

Comment: это не странная проблема, вы просто делаете неправильно. работу с элементами необходимо проводить в адаптере (в getView). ListView переиспользует элементы, как минимум вы можете столкнуться к перекраской не тех элементов, как максимум получите (и получаете) исключение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему таким методом, нарыв его в недрах английского SO

```
private View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```